# Graphql shield asks to enable cors on express server

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, nodejs-server

I installed graphql shield and using it with Apollo graphql. Since I use shield, I get an error regarding cors every time I execute a mutation. I am not sure why this happens as I am calling the Api just as before from my own server. I also tried to enable cors on my Node.js server but still some cross origin error occurs.

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This one!

```
const cors = require('cors')

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    credentials: true,

}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```